# Python How Can I make base class file can import from child class file

Tags: python, class, import, importerror

I meet a python import loop problem. And I don't want merge the two pieces code into one file. What can i do?

```
$ tree
.
├── testBase.py
└── testChild.py
```

testBase.py：

```
from testChild import Child

class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, obj):

        ## For some rease need detect obj
        if isinstance(obj,  Child):
            print("test")
```

testChild.py:

```
from testBase import Base

class Child(Base):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

With Error:

```
$ python testChild.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testChild.py", line 1, in <module>
    from testBase import Base
  File "/cygdrive/d/Home/test_import/testBase.py", line 2, in <module>
    from testChild import Child
  File "/cygdrive/d/Home/test_import/testChild.py", line 1, in <module>
    from testBase import Base
ImportError: cannot import name Base
```

I can make import in run time like this:

```
class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, obj):
        from testChild import Child
        ## For some rease need detect obj
        if isinstance(obj,  Child):
            print("test")
```

I want to know Is this the only way to fix this problem? Is there a good method?

Comment: That's the most normal way to do it . . . However, in general, a Base class shouldn't have to know anything about it's child classes.  Forcing the Base to know about the child is a bit of a code-smell.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - you have two files trying to import from each other, a parent class (too?) closely coupled to its child and haven't said why they can't be in a single file.

Comment: Sounds like a job for overloading your child method to me.

Comment: You should read this article about Importing Python Modules particularly the section on *Circular Imports* http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Comment: @Thimble obj may be a instance of child , list , or dict. child can use the parent's construct methond, so I can make child instance from different type (like childA from childB)

Comment: I second the people above with respect to code smell and division of responsibility/abstraction concerns.  There's also the option of implementing the logic in the conditional part of `__init__` in a separate method in each child, then calling that from `Base.__init__`.  If you absolutely need to do type-based logic in the base class `__init__` though, you could get away with it with a metaclass interface that registers handlers when each child is defined in a dict, then do a look up in to the handler registry in `Base.__init__` to do what you need.

Comment: Ultimately though, subclass specific logic should live with the subclass, not the superclass.  It's good design, and as a side effect, it helps to eliminate circular reference issues.

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to use `Base.__init__` as a factory method.  I'd suggest letting `__init__` be the initializer for an instance, then creating a separate instance or class method to act as a factory.

Comment: @Silas Ray could you answer the question using code example as you say 1 using metaclass 2 using seprate instance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the error message you are getting by avoiding the use of `from` in your imports:

testBase.py:

```
import testChild
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        ## For some rease need detect obj
        if isinstance(obj,  testChild.Child):
            print("test")
```

testChild.py:

```
import testBase
class Child(testBase.Base):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Comment: But, the comments on your question are correct: after you fix your design problem, this coding problem just goes away.